# TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
import os
os.system ("clear") 

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('1000x600')

def submit():
    submit_text = Label(root, text="Todays income is" + Textbox.get())
    submit_text.pack()




Label = Label(root, text='Enter the first mounth')
Label.pack()

Textbox = Entry(root, width=30)
Textbox.pack()

Button = Button(root, text="submit", command=submit)
Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

i wrote this and got this error.i dont know where i messed up cuz i watched a youtube tutorial and trying to make a desktop project

```
  File "d:\projects\P1.PY", line 10, in submit
    submit_text = Label(root, text="Todays income is" + Textbox.get())
TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable
```

i am very new and started coding today any help?

Comment: is there any Label class? does the object belong to a certain class?

Comment: you named your variable `Label`, which overwrites the actual Label class. Name it something else, like instruction_label. Same goes for Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the issue is here.

```
Label = Label(root, text='Enter the first mounth')
Label.pack()
```

`Label` is now a `Label` object(not a `Label` class anymore). So try renaming the variable name. For example,

```
label = Label(root, text='Enter the first mounth')
label.pack()
```